# docker: Error response from daemon: SIGILL: illegal instruction

Tags: docker, daemon

**Problem**

I'm trying to create a docker container from a common image `bitnami/airflow`. I successfully downloaded the image, but when I run `docker run -d -p 8080:8080 bitnami/airflow webserver` I get the following error:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: SIGILL: illegal instruction
```

- Docker version 20.10.8, build 3967b7d
- Problem occurs with several images I've tested

**Question**

Is there a simple explanation why that would be the case? Any way to fix it?

**Full Stack Trace**

Here is the full stack trace:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: SIGILL: illegal instruction
PC=0x809b5f m=6 sigcode=2
instruction bytes: 0x48 0xfe 0xfe 0xfe 0xff 0x0 0x74 0x1b 0xf 0x57 0xc0 0xf 0x11 0x84 0x24 0xc0

goroutine 1 [running]:
regexp.(*Regexp).doMatch(...)
        /usr/local/go/src/regexp/exec.go:514
regexp.(*Regexp).MatchString(...)
        /usr/local/go/src/regexp/regexp.go:525
github.com/containerd/containerd/identifiers.Validate(0x7ffd389a4e0c, 0x4, 0x7ffd389a4e0c, 0x4)
        /go/src/github.com/containerd/containerd/identifiers/validate.go:61 +0x9f fp=0xc0001575b0 sp=0xc000157500 pc=0x809b5f
github.com/containerd/containerd/namespaces.NamespaceRequired(0x9f5b60, 0xc000098000, 0x0, 0x8, 0x0, 0x7ff016885b10)
        /go/src/github.com/containerd/containerd/namespaces/context.go:74 +0xd5 fp=0xc000157618 sp=0xc0001575b0 pc=0x814dd5
github.com/containerd/containerd/runtime/v2/runc/v2.newCommand(0x9f5b60, 0xc000098000, 0x7ffd389a4e6e, 0x40, 0x7ffd389a4e56, 0x13, 0x7ffd389a4e1a, 0x2b, 0xc00002a00e, 0x31, ...)
        /go/src/github.com/containerd/containerd/runtime/v2/runc/v2/service.go:135 +0x4d fp=0xc000157708 sp=0xc000157618 pc=0x892ead
github.com/containerd/containerd/runtime/v2/runc/v2.(*service).StartShim(0xc000090080, 0x9f5b60, 0xc000098000, 0x7ffd389a4e6e, 0x40, 0x7ffd389a4e56, 0x13, 0x7ffd389a4e1a, 0x2b, 0xc00002a00e, ...)
        /go/src/github.com/containerd/containerd/runtime/v2/runc/v2/service.go:175 +0xcb fp=0xc000157970 sp=0xc000157708 pc=0x8934eb
github.com/containerd/containerd/runtime/v2/shim.run(0x976d27, 0x15, 0x98d508, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
        /go/src/github.com/containerd/containerd/runtime/v2/shim/shim.go:222 +0xbb5 fp=0xc000157ea8 sp=0xc000157970 pc=0x867e75
github.com/containerd/containerd/runtime/v2/shim.Run(0x976d27, 0x15, 0x98d508, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
        /go/src/github.com/containerd/containerd/runtime/v2/shim/shim.go:153 +0xc7 fp=0xc000157f48 sp=0xc000157ea8 pc=0x8671a7
main.main()
        /go/src/github.com/containerd/containerd/cmd/containerd-shim-runc-v2/main.go:27 +0x53 fp=0xc000157f88 sp=0xc000157f48 pc=0x898f73
runtime.main()
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:204 +0x209 fp=0xc000157fe0 sp=0xc000157f88 pc=0x438549
runtime.goexit()
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1374 +0x1 fp=0xc000157fe8 sp=0xc000157fe0 pc=0x46b0a1

goroutine 18 [chan receive]:
github.com/containerd/containerd/runtime/v2/shim.setRuntime.func1()
        /go/src/github.com/containerd/containerd/runtime/v2/shim/shim.go:120 +0x85
created by github.com/containerd/containerd/runtime/v2/shim.setRuntime
        /go/src/github.com/containerd/containerd/runtime/v2/shim/shim.go:119 +0x45

goroutine 5 [syscall]:
os/signal.signal_recv(0xc00003c7ae)
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/sigqueue.go:147 +0x9d
os/signal.loop()
        /usr/local/go/src/os/signal/signal_unix.go:23 +0x25
created by os/signal.Notify.func1.1
        /usr/local/go/src/os/signal/signal.go:150 +0x45

goroutine 6 [chan receive]:
github.com/containerd/containerd/runtime/v2/shim.(*RemoteEventsPublisher).processQueue(0xc000068180)
        /go/src/github.com/containerd/containerd/runtime/v2/shim/publisher.go:80 +0x55
created by github.com/containerd/containerd/runtime/v2/shim.NewPublisher
        /go/src/github.com/containerd/containerd/runtime/v2/shim/publisher.go:56 +0x10f

goroutine 7 [syscall]:
syscall.Syscall6(0xe8, 0xa, 0xc0001559a8, 0x80, 0xffffffffffffffff, 0x0, 0x0, 0x406d7a, 0xc00015e2a0, 0x0)
        /usr/local/go/src/syscall/asm_linux_amd64.s:41 +0x5
github.com/containerd/containerd/vendor/golang.org/x/sys/unix.EpollWait(0xa, 0xc0001559a8, 0x80, 0x80, 0xffffffffffffffff, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
        /go/src/github.com/containerd/containerd/vendor/golang.org/x/sys/unix/zsyscall_linux_amd64.go:77 +0x72
github.com/containerd/containerd/pkg/oom/v1.(*epoller).Run(0xc000068360, 0x9f5b60, 0xc000098000)
        /go/src/github.com/containerd/containerd/pkg/oom/v1/v1.go:77 +0xad
created by github.com/containerd/containerd/runtime/v2/runc/v2.New
        /go/src/github.com/containerd/containerd/runtime/v2/runc/v2/service.go:90 +0x109

goroutine 8 [runnable]:
github.com/containerd/containerd/runtime/v2/runc/v2.(*service).processExits(0xc000090080)
        /go/src/github.com/containerd/containerd/runtime/v2/runc/v2/service.go:726
created by github.com/containerd/containerd/runtime/v2/runc/v2.New
        /go/src/github.com/containerd/containerd/runtime/v2/runc/v2/service.go:100 +0x21f

goroutine 9 [runnable]:
github.com/containerd/containerd/vendor/github.com/containerd/console.(*Epoller).Wait(0xc0000683f0, 0xc0001578b0, 0x40df98)
        /go/src/github.com/containerd/containerd/vendor/github.com/containerd/console/console_linux.go:108
created by github.com/containerd/containerd/runtime/v2/runc.NewPlatform
        /go/src/github.com/containerd/containerd/runtime/v2/runc/platform.go:48 +0x5b

goroutine 10 [runnable]:
github.com/containerd/containerd/runtime/v2/runc/v2.(*service).forward(0xc000090080, 0x9f5b60, 0xc000098000, 0x9ef7e0, 0xc000068180)
        /go/src/github.com/containerd/containerd/runtime/v2/runc/v2/service.go:800
created by github.com/containerd/containerd/runtime/v2/runc/v2.New
        /go/src/github.com/containerd/containerd/runtime/v2/runc/v2/service.go:106 +0x2c5

rax    0xce0a20
rbx    0xc0000a8000
rcx    0x0
rdx    0x0
rdi    0xc00005c1e0
rsi    0x0
rbp    0xc0001575a0
rsp    0xc000157500
r8     0xce0a20
r9     0x0
r10    0xc00005c1e0
r11    0x4
r12    0xc000143b80
r13    0x0
r14    0x9dc890
r15    0x0
rip    0x809b5f
rflags 0x10202
cs     0x33
fs     0x0
gs     0x0
: exit status 2: unknown.
```